# JSON Parsing NodeJS and MongoDB

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

I have the following code that I am getting from a service:

```
  [{
    "_id": "58954f3bf36d2814d65a9aba",
    "School": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "X"
    }
}, {
    "_id": "58954f68f36d2814d65a9abb",
    "School": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Y"
    }
}, {
    "_id": "58954fa7f36d2814d65a9abc",
    "School": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Z"
    }
}]
```

I would like to send an Array of School back to the user how can I do it Node? Currently I have a router which accesses the database and returns all the rows. But I would prefer to send the correct type. My Node code is as follows

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var  mongojs  =  require('mongojs');
var db = someData;

//Get all users
router.get('/x', function(req, res, next) {
    // find everything
    console.log('x service called') 
    db.s.find(function (err,  ss)  {    
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
        console.log(ss)
        res.json(ss);
    });
});

// private extractData(res: Response) {
//     if (res.status < 200 || res.status >= 300) {
//         throw new Error('Bad response status: ' + res.status);
//     }
//     let body = res.json();
//     return body.data || {};
// }

module.exports = router;
```

Thanks

Comment: you just want to send array of schools? without _id? from the mentioned array ?

Comment: Please provide an example of output object

Comment: All I need is [{
    "School": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "X"
    }
}, {
   "School": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Y"
    }
}, {
    "School": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Z"
    }
}]

Answer (score 0):

You should need to stringify the ss object

```
var express = require('express'); 
var router = express.Router(); 
var  mongojs  =  require('mongojs');   
 var db = someData; 
 router.get('/x', function(req, res, next)
 {  console.log('x service called') 
 db.s.find(function (err,  ss)  
{     if (err) { 
                res.send(err);
                   } 

      else{
                  console.log(ss) 
                 ss=JSON.stringify(ss);
                  res.send(ss);
             }
           }); });
          module.exports = router;
```

At client side you need to

```
var ss=JSON.parse(ss);
```

So that you can extract the data from server

Comment: Stringification is not necessary if you are using res.json of express. It internally stringifies and sets the cintent tyoe headers

Comment: Should I user json.parse(string, reviver) ?